# Angular Copy clicked object to another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller, angular-factory

I have a list of items and if I click on one of them the current object should be copied to another controller and displayed there, I've created the factory to save the clicked item, but is not being displayed in the second controller view, I dont understand why is not showing.

Here's the plnker https://plnkr.co/edit/hWjFJCJcq3vtvefzFMOy

And the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angucomplete</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container" ng-controller="ControllerOne">
                <h3>Controller One</h3>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Rol Id</th>
                        <th>Rol Name</th>
                        <th>Rol Activo </th>
                        <th>Acciones </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="rol in roles">
                            <td>{{rol.rolId}}</td>
                            <td>{{rol.rolName}}</td>
                            <td>{{rol.rolActivo}}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" ng-click="propiedades(rol)"> <span class="fa fa-search"></span>  </a>   </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <pre>{{ rol }}</pre>
            </div>

            <div class="container" ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
                <h3>Controller Two</h3>

                RolId: {{ rol.rolId  }} <br>
                RolName: {{ rol.rolName }} <br>
                RolActvio: {{ rol.rolActivo }} <br>


            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

            app.factory('Data', function(){
                return{
                    currentRol:{},  
                    setCurrentRol: function(rol){
                        this.currentRol = rol;
                        console.log( 'Desde service set: ' + JSON.stringify( this.currentRol ) );
                    }
                }
            });

            app.controller('ControllerOne', function($scope, Data){
                $scope.propiedades = function(rol){
                  $scope.rol = rol;
                    Data.setCurrentRol(rol);                                    
                }

                $scope.roles =[
                    {rolId: 1, rolName:"Administrador", rolActivo:"26/10/2016"},
                    {rolId: 2, rolName:"DBA", rolActivo:"25/08/2016"},
                    {rolId: 3, rolName:"Tester", rolActivo:"01/01/2016"},
                    {rolId: 4, rolName:"Ingeniero de Desarrollo", rolActivo:"12/11/2015"},
                    {rolId: 5, rolName:"Ingeniero de Pruebas", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                    {rolId: 6, rolName:"Secretario", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                    {rolId: 7, rolName:"VICE", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                    {rolId: 8, rolName:"Arquitecto", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                ];

            })// Fin controller one 

            app.controller('ControllerTwo', function($scope, Data){
                $scope.rol = Data.currentRol;

            })// Fin controller two

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `broadcast` as below,

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angucomplete</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container" ng-controller="ControllerOne">
                <h3>Controller One</h3>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Rol Id</th>
                        <th>Rol Name</th>
                        <th>Rol Activo </th>
                        <th>Acciones </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="rol in roles">
                            <td>{{rol.rolId}}</td>
                            <td>{{rol.rolName}}</td>
                            <td>{{rol.rolActivo}}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" ng-click="propiedades(rol)"> <span class="fa fa-search"></span>  </a>   </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <pre>{{ rol }}</pre>
            </div>

            <div class="container" ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
                <h3>Controller Two</h3>

                RolId: {{ rol.rolId  }} <br>
                RolName: {{ rol.rolName }} <br>
                RolActvio: {{ rol.rolActivo }} <br>


            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

            app.factory('Data', function(){
                return{
                    currentRol:{},  
                    setCurrentRol: function(rol){
                        this.currentRol = rol;
                        console.log( 'Desde service set: ' + JSON.stringify( this.currentRol ) );
                    }
                }
            });

            app.controller('ControllerOne', function($scope, $rootScope, Data){
                $scope.propiedades = function(rol){
                  $scope.rol = Data.currentRol = rol;
                  Data.setCurrentRol(rol);                     
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('dataChanged');
                }

                $scope.roles =[
                    {rolId: 1, rolName:"Administrador", rolActivo:"26/10/2016"},
                    {rolId: 2, rolName:"DBA", rolActivo:"25/08/2016"},
                    {rolId: 3, rolName:"Tester", rolActivo:"01/01/2016"},
                    {rolId: 4, rolName:"Ingeniero de Desarrollo", rolActivo:"12/11/2015"},
                    {rolId: 5, rolName:"Ingeniero de Pruebas", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                    {rolId: 6, rolName:"Secretario", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                    {rolId: 7, rolName:"VICE", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                    {rolId: 8, rolName:"Arquitecto", rolActivo:"06/03/2016"},
                ];

            })// Fin controller one 

            app.controller('ControllerTwo', function($scope, Data){
                $scope.rol = Data.currentRol;
                $scope.$on('dataChanged', function() {
                  $scope.rol = Data.currentRol;
                });

            })// Fin controller two

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a setter function in your service, but you also need a getter function to retrieve the data in the new controller. When you set the data in the service, store it in a variable. Then from your getter return that variable. Then you can set a scope variable in your new controller which calls the getter function  and now you'll have the data in the new controller.